# How to create table within the jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to fetch some details in the table and load it into a table within the jquery dialog.

I tried coding the table inside the `div` id using html table, but it does't load in the dialog.

```
<div id = "downloadModal" style="display:none">
<form>
<fieldset>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Action</th>
         <th>File Name</th>
         <th>File Size</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include  in your table after .If you are loading the data through ajax my suggestion would be append the data to the  by giving a 'id' to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){

            dialogCust = $("#custAddList").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 950,
            modal: true
        });

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceUrl ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(item.Name),
                                $('<td>').text(item.Code)
                            ).appendTo('#custAddList').last().after();
                        });
                        dialogCust.dialog("open");
                    } else {
                        alert("Not found address for customer.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(c);
                }
            });
         });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="custAddList">

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```